# iOS app with slider and 2 button on a view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am creating an application in iOS in which there is slider usage. My slider is working fine, but on one of my view there are two button named CALCULATE and EDIT. the action performed on calculate is working but my EDIT is not working even when the button is linked to UIView.

Error is : unrecognized selector send to instance

Comment: how you are setting the selector to your edit button, post your code into question.

Comment: Show the code of Edit button. If you are getting error on Edit button, then your question is not really about the slider. How do you hook up the action for editButton? Through storyboard? programmatically?

Comment: I do the action of edit button through storyboard

Comment: I have no code on edit button . I have linked edit button to view from storyboard

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have code and when you press button you get "unrecognized selector send to instance".

To fix this, select your button in the storyboard (or .xib) and check 'Sent Events' on it, then remove any events.

[image]

Comment: Please add this as a comment to the question, since it's not really an answer.

Comment: @iosDev82 I can't, because i had 26 reputation, now 24, thank you. To add comments i need 50. When i see come code i'll edit my post.